# DotNet Assembly.LoadFrom returns null, FUSLOGVW.exe logs assembly loaded

Tags: .net, .net-assembly

I have an dll that should be loaded via `Assembly.LoadFrom`. It does work on my local VM which has - as far as I know - the same setup as the machine on which it does not work. According to the dependency tool that I used no dependencies are missing.

I logged the information via FUSLOGVW.exe and it says that it was successful:

```
FUSLOGVW.exe
The operation was successful.
Bind reslt: hr = 0x0. The operation completed successfully.
...
LOG: Assembly is loaded in LoadFrom load context.
```

Note: The DotNet Framework version shown in the log-file is the same on both my local and the machine on which it does not work.

Despite it being successful `Assembly.LoadFrom` returns null.

Comment: Do you have any custom assembly resolution handlers?

Comment: I have a ResolveEventHandler which does **not** get called. Is that what you mean?